# Get post by its ID (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I get a Custom Post by its ID in wordpress and show its thumbnail, title and content? Here is what I am using, but didnt the content is messed up.

```
<div class="left-cont1">
        <div class="left-cont1-text">       
            <?php
            query_posts('post_id=790&post_type=homepage');
            while (have_posts()): the_post();
            ?>
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
          <div class="cont1-border"></div>
          <p><?php echo(types_render_field("homepage-content", array("raw"=>"true"))); ?></p>
          <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>/more/"><?php echo(types_render_field("homepage-urltitle", array("raw"=>"true"))); ?></a></h2>           
        </div>
        <div class="left-cont1-image1"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'home-circle'); ?></div>
        <?php endwhile;?>
      </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the content is messed up"? Is it pulling in the wrong post, nothing, or...?

Comment: Hi, @Andrew. everything is repeating like it is showing up same thumbnail, post, etc multiple times in a page. I wanted to show up only four posts.

Comment: In the code that you posted, you are only pulling in the single post with ID=790. This means that any loop after this will pull in only that post. Also, `$page->ID` will not get the ID of the post currently in the loop. If you want that, use `get_the_ID()`

Comment: Hi @Andrew, Thanks a lot for the reply. I am very new to WordPress and php world. I would like to display 4 different post in a separate div. Each div containing the title, thumbnail and content of the particular post. I have posts IDs 790, 771, 810 and 805. Is there simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to take your current code, change `get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'home-circle')` to `get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_id(), 'home-circle')`, and replicate your code for each post you want to pull in, modifying the `post_id=xxx` to match the ID of the post you want to pull in.

This is not the most attractive solution, but from the information you gave, it should at least work. Just so you know, there is an entire StackExchange site devoted to Wordpress: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where you should be able to get more Wordpress-specific answers. If your question is about PHP, please feel free to ask here, but if it is Wordpress-specific, your better bet would be the dedicated Wordpress site.

Since you're new to PHP, I would recommend getting an introductory book or two and try to get some of the basic concepts down pat before working with WordPress. While there will be a larger up-front investment of time, it will pay off in the long run. Good luck!